# Selecionar por posição em varchar

Tags: mysql

Tenho no banco de dados mysql um campo `documento` do tipo `varchar`.

Os registros seguem o seguinte padrão:
`123456789`,`12X456789`.
Ou todo em números ou contendo uma letra na terceira posição.

Como monto um `select` para capturar apenas os registro que possuem letras na terceira posição?

Tentei como `like` porém tive que montar um select para cada letra do alfabeto:

`select * from tabela where documento like '11A%'`
`select * from tabela where documento like '11B%'`
`select * from tabela where documento like '11C%'`

Como faço isso de forma mais eficiente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode filtrar com **REGEXP** na coluna documento, dessa forma o MySQL utilizará a expressão regular que você especificar para encontrar seu resultado. [Aqui](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx) tem um bom tutorial sobre.

Exemplo do uso de **REGEXP** no MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    documento
FROM
    tabela
WHERE
    documento REGEXP '^.{2}[a-z]'
ORDER BY documento;
```

Resumindo o regex grosseiramente seria isso:

- ^ indica o começo do registro
- . indica um caractere qualquer
- {n} número de instâncias antes do caractere que você vai especificar
- [a-z] especifica que você quer caracteres do alfabeto

Comment: Funcionou bem mesmo a regex. obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE
  test.id RLIKE '^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]*$'
```

Para encontrar correspondências entre os valores de uma coluna e uma expressão regular especificada use o operador [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

No caso o padrão especificado na pergunta é:

- Todos os elemento são números.
- O terceiro elemento pode ser um número ou letra.
- Na pergunta não foi especificado o comprimento desse valor o deixei variável, cabendo o autor da pergunta fazer o ajuste ou pedir orientação nos comentários.

Na documentação [MySQl::Correspondência de padrões](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) está especificado:

> `.` corresponde a qualquer caractere único.
>
> Uma classe de caractere `[...]` corresponde a qualquer caractere entre
>   colchetes. `[a-z]` corresponde a qualquer letra, enquanto `[0-9]` corresponde a qualquer dígito.
>
> `*` corresponde a zero ou mais instâncias do que a precede.
>
> use `^`e `$`para corresponder ao início e ao fim.
>
> use o operador `{n}` para repetir o padrão n vezes.

Então lendo o padrão `'^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]*$'` textualmente o padrão significaria:

> Que comece com dois dígitos numéricos, o terceiro caractere seja letra
>   ou dígito numérico e que termine com zero ou mais dígitos numéricos.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ("123456789");
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ("12bb00233");
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ("12X456789");
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ("120c98755");

SELECT * FROM test
WHERE
  test.id RLIKE '^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]*$'
```

Resultado:

```
id
---------
123456789
12X456789
```

Exemplo testável no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n2WP5uk4ossZHzdCQRXLiR/0):

Answer (score -1):

Os registros são definidos em números ou é uma string? Se somente os registros que você busca serão Strings, você pode tentar Converter o valor em um INT e pegar só os valores que não foram convertidos.

```
SELECT CAST('documento' AS UNSIGNED) FROM 'TABELA'
```

Caso ele não consiga converter, você sabe que o valor é uma string e você vai pegar esse valor em especifico.